# Build Shapeless implicit in the function

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a use case where I create an HList Record and pass it to a different function, and select an element in the function it was passed to. I couldn't find a way to make any of the following work:

Pass an `HList` to the function with a `Witness` defined in the function:

```
  def sel0[L <: HList](hl: L) = {
    val w = Witness('field1)
    implicit val selector = the[Selector[L, w.T]]
    selector(hl)
  }
```

or pass and `HList` and a `Witness` and build the `Selector` in the function

```
  def sel1[L <: HList](hl: L, w: Witness) = {
    implicit val selector = the[Selector[L, w.T]]
    selector(hl)
  }
```

Not even a simpler version where the implicit in contructed from the `Witness` before sent to the function:

```
  val hl = 'field1 ->> 1 :: 'field2 ->> "2" :: HNil
  val w = Witness('field1)
  val selector = the[Selector[hl.type, w.T]]

  def sel2[L <: HList](hl: L, w: Witness)(implicit selector: Selector[L, w.T]) = {
    selector(hl)
  }

  sel2(r1, w)(selector)
```

Any suggestion why these above don't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one

```
def sel0[L <: HList](hl: L)(implicit 
  selector: shapeless.ops.hlist.Selector[L, FieldType[Witness.`'field1`.T, Int]]) = 
  selector(hl)
```

or this

```
def sel0[L <: HList](hl: L)(implicit 
  selector: shapeless.ops.record.Selector[L, Witness.`'field1`.T]) = 
  selector(hl)
```

<strike>`selector(selector)` is very strange.</strike>

You don't need `hl.type`. It's the type of this particular `hl`. The correct type of `hl` is the type of all such `hl`s, i.e. `` Record.`'field1 -> Int, 'field2 -> String`.T `` or `` FieldType[Witness.`'field1`.T, Int] :: FieldType[Witness.`'field2`.T, String] :: HNil ``.

Comment: thank you. would any of these work with constructing the implicit inside the function similar to `sel0` or `sel1` in my examples?

Comment: @jamborta No, this is not how implicits work in Scala.

Comment: @jamborta For example `the[Sum.Aux[_2, _3, _5]]` compiles and
`def test[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, NplusM <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum.Aux[N, M, NplusM]) = ???` compiles but
`def test1[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, NplusM <: Nat] = the[Sum.Aux[N, M, NplusM]]` doesn't.

Comment: I can summon an implicit from the standard library in Scala. For example `implicitly[Ordering[Int]]` would work as long as the implicit is in the context. My question really is why that is not the case for the examples above.

Comment: @jamborta According to [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), types are statements and values of those types are proofs of the statements. When you say `def test(implicit x: X) = ???` you say "do `???` with additional assumption that `X` has been proved" and this assumption is checked when `test(..)` is called. When you say `implicitly[X]` or (`the[X]`) you say "check now that `X` has been proved".

Comment: `implicitly[Ordering[Int]]` compiles since compiler knows that type `Int` is an instance of type class `Ordering`. `implicitly[Sum.Aux[_2, _3, _5]]` compiles since compiler knows that 2+3=5 (it knows how to check this from definition of type class `Sum`). `def test[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, NplusM <: Nat](implicit sum: Sum.Aux[N, M, NplusM]) = ???` compiles since compiler doesn't check that `N + M = NplusM` now, it does `???` in assumption that `N + M = NplusM` and `N + M = NplusM` will be checked for specific `N`, `M`, `NplusM` when `test(..)` is called.

Comment: `implicitly[Sum.Aux[N, M, NplusM]]` doesn't compile since compiler doesn't know now that `N + M = NplusM` (`N`, `M`, `NplusM` are just three arbitrary natural numbers). Similarly `implicitly[Selector[Record.`'field1 -> Int, 'field2 -> String`.T, Witness.`'field1`.T]]` compiles since compiler knows that in a record of type `Record.`'field1 -> Int, 'field2 -> String`.T, Witness.`'field1`.T` there is a key of type `Witness.`'field1`.T` (it knows how to check this from definition of type class `Selector`).

Comment: `def test[L <: HList, K <: Symbol](implicit selector: Selector[L, K]) = ???` compiles since compiler doesn't check presence of key `K` now, this will be checked for specific `L` and `K` when the function is called. `def test1[L <: HList, K <: Symbol] = implicitly[Selector[L, K]]` or `def test2[L <: HList, K <: Symbol] = Selector[L, K]` don't compile since compiler doesn't know how to check this now (and it's not true for arbitrary `L`, `K`). This is how implicits work in Scala.

Comment: Writing `implicit val selector = the[Selector[L, w.T]]` or `implicit val selector = implicitly[Selector[L, w.T]]` is pointless. You do not provide additional implicit, it's the same implicit as `implicitly[Selector[L, w.T]]` (if it were found in the scope). So it's the same as just `val selector = implicitly[Selector[L, w.T]]`.

Comment: You can write also ``type hlType = Record.`'field1 -> Int, 'field2 -> String`.T;
val w = Witness('field1);
implicitly[Selector[hlType, w.T]]`` so that this compiles.

Comment: So compiler can check proofs for specific `N, M, L, K` but can't for arbitrary `N, M, L, K` (since for arbitrary `N, M, L, K` it's not true).